# what means % s.something()%__name__ in Python

Tags: python, module

I am studying Python little by little and one of my main source of studying is somebody else's scripts. I tried to google it, but i can't wrap it up around my head. What means  % s.something()%**name** ?

I can't put exact code in , but for example (sorry little Maya sample):

```
mc.textScrollList(ams=False,fn='plainLabelFont',p=_ui['mainLay'],sc='%s.listSelected()' % __name__)
```

def listSelected():
   some script which returns list

I read that % it's a module , but i don't understand how it works with definitions and what means '**name**' there?
I understand question is a little bit bad stated and  without any normal example , but if somebody can understand and explain it to me I will really appreciate it !

Thanks!

Comment: "Old" python string formatting, more info here https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an "older" form of formatting things into strings. The preferred way (python 3 up) is

```
print('some{:d}'.format(22))  # with format appended and placeholder
```

or

```
print ( f'some{22:d}' )  # inline formatting
```

will format the number 22 into the string as decimal. Yours is similar, but in your example it will format the content of  `__name__` into your string, `__name__` is set by your class/module - resulting in a string of `<classname>.listSelected()`.

See : https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

```
print('some{:d}'.format(22))
print('Hello %s' % "World")  # similar to yours - using python 3, python 2: use no ()
```

Output:

```
some22
Hello World
```

For more information, see [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)